# SIM800C : Uploaded audio AMR file has noise when played during call

Tags: audio, gsm, sim800

1. I am able to upload the AMR file to SIM800C successfully.
2. When I play the uploaded audio file during the call using the below command :

```
       #if CALL_RECORDED_AUDIO
        Serial1.print("AT+CMEDPLAY=1,C:\\REC\\");                            
           // "Command Media PLAY" -> to play an audio if it is a recorded audio
       #else    
        Serial1.print("AT+CMEDPLAY=1,C:\\User\\");                           
          // "Command Media PLAY" -> to play an audio if it is a uploaded audio
       #endif
```

Played audio always has noise, from `C:\User\`.

3. However if I record the audio during call and save it. Play the recorded audio during next call then there is no noise. ( By defining `CALL_RECORDED_AUDIO` in above code snippet)

Answer (score 1):

according to the documentation of the sim800 it is necessary to play a sound wav during the call

> Note
>
> > .  mode 2 and 3 are not supported when playing audio file during call.
> >
> > . The audio file can not be played duirng incoming call or outgoing call.
> >
> > . Only support WAV, PCM, AMR and MP3 format.
> >
> > . Only support WAV format with 8K 16bit during call.

page 201/202 of the  [sim800 guide](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf)

personally i did not suck having no sim800

I think the recording of a call must be in .WAV format

let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

The audio you play aould also be in AMR format:

```
AT+CMEDPLAY=1,C:\\REC\\4.AMR,1,95
```

I have played audio files using this command with no problems